# so i installed sql server now how do i connect to it?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, visual-studio

SO i have a server running windows server 2008 r2 and i just installed Microsoft sql server 2008. I used the manager thing to create the database and the tables, etc and now i want to connect to it via my visual studio which is on a different machine. so how do i do that? do i need to "turn on" the sql server, do i need to do port forwarding? do i have to modify the iis  or change those settings? is there a good article someone can me point me to? just to further help you help me, i understand how to connect to a datasource in visual studio my problem is more with the sql server and understanding how to properly set it up once installed.

Sorry for the noob question, i got it all installed and i know how to use it once its all going i just don't know the in-between.

thanks in advance
dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should check if TCP is enabled in your SQL Server instance, and enable it if it's not:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294(v=SQL.100).aspx

Then, you need to configure Windows Firewall on the server to allow incoming connections to your database:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx

Comment: perfect, the windows firewall article was difficult to follow, im not sure it was for my setup but it helped me figure it out.

thanks again soo much